# Capture volume/dimension information in a string using regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I can easily capture values and their respected units like 100 m, 10 GB, 75mm, 5 kg using the following regex

```
import re
pattern = "(?P<val>\d+\.?\d?)\s*(?P<unit>(mm|m|GB))" 
r = re.search(pattern, p)
if r:
    val, unit = float(r.group('val')), r.group('unit')
```

But now I have volume or dimensions in a string for like `150.0 x 50.0 x 200.0 mm`. How can I detect the difference in these two formats and parse the dimensions. Because If I apply the existing regex pattern to this it will detect only `200.0 mm` part and returns me only this which is wrong. 
The expected results should be like `['150.0 mm', '50.0 mm', '200.0 mm']`. How can I get this result ? Thanks

Comment: Without some post-processing, you won't get this result because there is only 1 `mm` in the string.

Comment: What about adding a trailing `?` to the pattern: `"(?P<val>\d+\.?\d?)\s*(?P<unit>(mm|m|GB))?"` so that units become optional?

Answer (score 1):

If your list is always separated by "x" you don't need a regex for this - you can just use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). If you will have multiple different separators you can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

def splitMetric(text):
    arr = re.split(r'x|&',text) #split to list - add your separator here
    #arr = text.split('x') - if it's always 'x'
    suff = text.rpartition(" ")[2] #get suffix - this is assuming all entries are like your example with a space before it
    for i in range(len(arr)-1): #add suffix to elements
        arr[i] = arr[i] + suff
    return arr

>>> splitMetric("150.0 x 50.0 x 200.0 mm")
['150.0 mm', ' 50.0 mm', ' 200.0 mm']
>>> splitMetric("150.0&50.0&200.0 m")
['150.0m', '50.0m', '200.0 m']
```